# Picture taken with camera as div background image Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, ionic3, background-image

I've got a picture, taken by the phone's camera and that results into something like `http://localhost:8080/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg`.

No matter what I try I can't get it to set the background-image for a given div. (using inline CSS on that div).

**So:** `<div style="background: url('{{ imageUrl }}');">` is not working (the div has height and width, and when I put the background to `yellow` I see a yellow background.

**While:** `<img src="{{ imageUrl }}"/>` is working.

**Also:** When I try a random image from Google, like `https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg`, it shows that image as the background image.

Is there some limitation to the URL format that can be given for a background-image in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ionic, it can be achieved by two ways as follows:
1] Using style.property binding as follows:

```
<div [style.backgroundImage]="imageUrl"></div>
```

2] Using ngStyle binding as follows:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : imageUrl}"></div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I had to alter your second solution a little by adding `url(' + imageUrl + ')'` but it works like a charm!